# How can I send nil picture as a Swift Data type in to REST service in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to upload pictures(with FTP way) by `REST Service`. So I have a function like below:

```
func saveFeedBack(feedbackType: String, feedbackText: String, picture1: Data, picture2: Data, picture3: Data)
    {
        let parameters = [
            "ofeedbackType": feedbackType,
            "ofeedbackText": feedbackText
        ]

        let oimage1 = UIImage(data: picture1)
        let oimage2 = UIImage(data: picture2)
        let oimage3 = UIImage(data: picture3)

        guard let mediaImage1 = Media(withImage: oimage1!, forKey: "pic1") else { return }
        guard let mediaImage2 = Media(withImage: oimage2!, forKey: "pic2") else { return }
        guard let mediaImage3 = Media(withImage: oimage3!, forKey: "pic3") else { return }

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://abc.def.com/Mobile/SSS/feedback") else { return }
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)


        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        let boundary = generateBoundary()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage1, mediaImage2, mediaImage3], boundary: boundary)
        request.httpBody = dataBody

        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                print(response)
            }

            if let data = data
            {
                do
                {
                    if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        //some code in here
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

Here is the Media struct:

```
import UIKit

struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String

    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "fotograf.jpg"

        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Let's talk about this scenario: Let's say I am sending `picture 1` and `picture 2`. But I am not sending `picture 3`. Of course I am getting below error because of this code:             `guard let mediaImage3 = Media(withImage: oimage3!, forKey: "pic3") else { return }`

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**How can I get rid of above problem? Pictures should be optional. I mean: functions should work fine if I don't send any picture.**

Here is the CreateDataBody function

```
func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {
        let lineBreak = "\r\n"
        var body = Data()

        if let parameters = params {
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
            }
        }

        if let media = media {
            for photo in media {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append(photo.data)
                body.append(lineBreak)
            }
        }

        body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

        return body
    }
```

Comment: set optionals with your model. like `let data: Data? ` accordingly

Comment: I did what you said. But this time this line: body.append(photo.data) Says this:Value of optional type 'Data?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Data'. Can you help me please? @Newbie

Comment: I have fixed 'body.append(photo.data)' like this 'body.append(photo.data!)' like XCode shows me. But same line gives an error if I try without picture 3: guard let mediaImage3 = Media(withImage: oimage3!, forKey: "resim3") else { return } error is same: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value @Newbie

Comment: try to use like this in your model `let data: Data? = nil`

Comment: I tried but it wanted me to change let with var. so I wrote this : var data: Data? = nil. And then I have tried. But it gave same error: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file @Newbie

Comment: do you have any example code run? can you share code with me ?

Comment: Dear Newbie, I wrote all details in my post already. ? @Newbie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
import UIKit

struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data?
    let mimeType: String

    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "photo.jpg"
        self.data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    }  
}

func createDataBody(withParameters params: Parameters?, media: [Media]?, boundary: String) -> Data {
        let lineBreak = "\r\n"
        var body = Data()

    if let parameters = params {
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
        }
    }

    if media != nil {
        print("media cnt: ", media!.count)

        if let media = media {
            for photo in media {
                body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(photo.key)\"; filename=\"\(photo.filename)\"\(lineBreak)")
                body.append("Content-Type: \(photo.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
                body.append(photo.data!)
                body.append(lineBreak)
                print("photo.key", photo.key)

            }
        }
    }



    body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")

    return body
}

func saveFeedBack(feedbackType: String, feedbackText: String, picture1: Data, picture2: Data, picture3: Data)
{
       var imageList : [Media] = []

       let parameters = [
           "ofeedbackType": feedbackType,
           "ofeedbackText": feedbackText
       ]


       if  let img1 = UIImage(data: picture1) {

           if img1.size.width > 0 {

               if let oImg1 = Media(withImage: img1, forKey: "pic1") {

                   imageListe.append(oImg1)
               }
           }
       }

       if  let img2 = UIImage(data: picture2) {

                  if img2.size.width > 0 {

                      if let oImg2 = Media(withImage: img2, forKey: "pic2") {

                          imageListe.append(oImg2)
                      }
                  }
              }

       if  let img3 = UIImage(data: picture3) {

                         if img3.size.width > 0 {

                             if let oImg3 = Media(withImage: img3, forKey: "pic3") {

                                 imageListe.append(oImg3)


                             }
                         }
                     }

       guard let url = URL(string: "http://abc.des.com/Test/SSS/feedback") else { return }
       var request = URLRequest(url: url)
       request.httpMethod = "POST"

       let boundary = generateBoundary()

       request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

       let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media:imageList , boundary: boundary)

    request.httpBody = dataBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data
        {
            do
            {
                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                {
                    //some code in here
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with that hopefully this will work. I have made some changes.

Model:

```
struct Media {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data
    let mimeType: String

    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "fotograf.jpg"

        guard let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return nil }
        self.data = data
    }
}
```

Code:

```
func saveFeedBack(feedbackType: String, feedbackText: String, picture1: Data, picture2: Data, picture3: Data)
{
    let parameters = [
        "ofeedbackType": feedbackType,
        "ofeedbackText": feedbackText
    ]

    guard let oimage1 = UIImage(data: picture1) else { return }
    guard let oimage2 = UIImage(data: picture2) else { return }
    guard let oimage3 = UIImage(data: picture3) else { return }



    let mediaImage1 = Media(withImage: oimage1, forKey: "pic1")
    let mediaImage2 = Media(withImage: oimage2, forKey: "pic2")
    let mediaImage3 = Media(withImage: oimage3, forKey: "pic3")

    guard let url = URL(string: "http://abc.def.com/Mobile/SSS/feedback") else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)


    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let boundary = generateBoundary()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let dataBody = createDataBody(withParameters: parameters, media: [mediaImage1, mediaImage2, mediaImage3], boundary: boundary)
    request.httpBody = dataBody

    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let response = response {
            print(response)
        }

        if let data = data
        {
            do
            {
                if let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
                {
                    //some code in here
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: thanks but how does the code continue after that guard line if guard line code goes in to else scope? guard let oimage3 = UIImage(data: picture3) else { return }   I tried without picture 3. code does not pass the guard let oimage3 line. It did not help unfortunately.

Comment: Its really surprising for me. I am also using `multipart form-data` with `Alamofire` and I used  data wrap optional value like `data ?? nil` because for Image there as such no unwrap value for `nil` check use guard or if statements. or last option is to use placeholder image types.

Comment: Understood my friend  but I should fix this code without 'Alamofire'.  I will keep waiting for solution :) Thanks @Newbie